# Ошибки при импорте любого пакета(unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, package

При импорте любого пакета выскакивают эти 3 ошибки. Пробовал очищать кэш в папке пакетов проекта и запускать unity от имени администратора - не помогает.[image]

Также снял видео что бы вы наглядно смогли увидеть в какой момент происходит ошибка и также в видео видно развернутый текст ошибок. [Видео можно посмотреть здесь.](https://youtu.be/5yfZg_ZZQnA)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Развернутый текст ошибок надо бы вставить текстом в пост.

Comment: Сделал скрины каждой ошибки.

Comment: Я вам пишу "вставить текстом в пост", а вы опять вставляете картинки. Что-то пошло не так.